Unable to add more than 2 adsterra ad banner on Next.js 14 app
I'm getting issue on adding more than 2 adsterra ad banner on Next.js 14 app. When I'm trying to render two Adsterra ad banner's on a same page,the first one is'nt rendering.
I also tried with next/script, getting same issue
First banner code:
"use client";

import classNames from "classnames";
import { HTMLAttributes, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const BannerAd468x60 = (props: HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>) => {
  const { className } = props;
  const container = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const isWindow = typeof window !== "undefined";

  const atOptions = {
    key: "abc",
    format: "iframe",
    height: 60,
    width: 468,
    params: {},
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isWindow && container.current && !container.current.firstChild) {
      const conf = document.createElement("script");
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = `//www.topcreativeformat.com/${atOptions.key}/invoke.js`;
      script.async = true;
      script.defer = true;
      conf.async = true;
      conf.defer = true;
      conf.innerHTML = `atOptions = ${JSON.stringify(atOptions)}`;

      container.current.append(conf);
      container.current.append(script);
    }
  }, [container, isWindow]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={container}
      className={classNames(
        "flex items-center justify-center",
        className && className
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default BannerAd468x60;


Second Banner code:
"use client";

import classNames from "classnames";
import { HTMLAttributes, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const BannerAd728x90 = (props: HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>) => {
  const { className } = props;
  const container = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const isWindow = typeof window !== "undefined";

  const atOptions = {
    key: "abc",
    format: "iframe",
    height: 90,
    width: 728,
    params: {},
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isWindow && container.current && !container.current.firstChild) {
      const conf = document.createElement("script");
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = `//www.topcreativeformat.com/${atOptions.key}/invoke.js`;
      script.async = true;
      script.defer = true;
      conf.async = true;
      conf.defer = true;
      conf.innerHTML = `atOptions = ${JSON.stringify(atOptions)}`;

      container.current.append(conf);
      container.current.append(script);
    }
  }, [container, isWindow]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={container}
      className={classNames(
        "flex items-center justify-center",
        className && className
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default BannerAd728x90;


Unable to add more than 2 adsterra ad banner on Next.js 14 app

Dear try using this this may work cause it works for me :)
"use client";

import classNames from "classnames";
import { HTMLAttributes, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Script from 'next/script';

const BannerAd468x60 = (props: HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>) => {
  const { className } = props;
  const container = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const atOptions = {
    key: "unique_key_1",
    format: "iframe",
    height: 60,
    width: 468,
    params: {},
  };

  return (
    <div
      ref={container}
      className={classNames(
        "flex items-center justify-center",
        className && className
      )}
    >
      <Script
        id="ad-script-468x60"
        strategy="lazyOnload"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
            var atOptions = ${JSON.stringify(atOptions)};
            (function() {
              var script = document.createElement('script');
              script.type = 'text/javascript';
              script.src = '//www.topcreativeformat.com/' + atOptions.key + '/invoke.js';
              script.async = true;
              script.defer = true;
              container.current.append(script);
            })();
          `,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BannerAd468x60;


I found the solution, It's working for me.


import classNames from "classnames";
import { HTMLAttributes } from "react";

const BannerAd468x60 = (props: HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>) => {
  const { className } = props;

  return (
    <div
      className={classNames(
        "flex items-center justify-center",
        className && className
      )}
    >
      <iframe
        src={`//www.topcreativeformat.com/watchnew?key=<KEY>`}
        width="468px"
        height="60px"
        scrolling="no"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BannerAd468x60;



